# Setting AWS S3 credentials in C# app

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core

I want to develop a simple app that could get AWS keys from command line and access AWS S3 service. All C# samples and AWS documentation on .Net that I have seen uses either SDK store, credential files or environment variables. Is there a way to just create AmazonS3Client and specify keys for it without creating external files or setting environment variables?

This is C# .net core 2.0. Eventually this app would run on linux and windows so platform-neutral approach would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the AWSAccessKey + AWSSecretKey to authenticate.

`AmazonS3Client` offers a constructor accepting an object of type AWSCredentials.

```
AmazonS3Client(AWSCredentials)
```

Just pass an instance of type `BasicAWSCredentials` specifying the two keys. You could get them from the arguments if needed

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client.htm

Have fun,

Seb